# Have a linear game with inventory in python, and want to allow the player to check their invetory

Tags: python, scripting

The problem I am having is allowing the player to check their inventory at any time during the game. I'm not sure how I go about doing that.  Is there something I can add to the code?  Bascially all we have to do is not make a creative or story driven game, but something that works.

```
# A not so amazing game.

import time

#Define Inventory
inventory = []




 #Name Input and Introduction
 name = input("Hello there what is your name? ")
 print ("Welcome {}! This will be a test to see if you are a PC or Console gamer.  Be wise for if you choose the wrong path it will surely lead to your death the game is about making the right choice".format(name))

time.sleep(3)

print("")

#Left or Right Path
print ("You come to a corridor, with two ways.  LEFT or RIGHT")
corridor = input("Which way do you go? ")

if corridor == "right":
    print("You take the path to the right and find a Hard Drive")
    inventory.append('hard drive')
    print(inventory)
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)

else: 
    print("You follow the left path, but you hurt yourself")
    time.sleep(3)

#Player Health
player_health = 100
if player_health <= 0:
    print("You think PC is an inferior platform to gaming, your wallet is empty, your eyes bleeding and you die a horrific death")
    exit(0)

#An encounter with a console, the player can either attack or flee.

print ("You find a console at the end of the corridor and it tries to attack you.")
console = input("Do you want to attack or flee? ")

if console == "attack":
    print("Well done, you have taken your first steps to becoming a PC gamer. You also find a GTX Titan GPU")
    inventory.append('titan')
    print(inventory)
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)

elif console !="attack" or console !="flee":
    print("You sat on the fence, and you fell off it.  You died")
    exit(0)

else:
    print("While you fled you tripped over on cables and hurt yourself worry not you can still prove your self")
    time.sleep(3)

#ALLOWS PLAYER TO CHECK INVENTORY BUT NOT ON DEMAND :'( 
print("Check your inventory before proceeding press enter")
iventory = input ("Just press enter" )
print(inventory)
print("")
time.sleep(5)


if player_health == 100:    

    #Question about mods
    print("A mysterious voice asks you a question")
    question_one = input ("Which of these these games has free mods SKYRIM or COD? ")

    if question_one == "skyrim":
         print("You are pleasing the voice! here's 50 health")
        player_health += 50
        time.sleep(3)

    else: 
        print("While you can mod COD you can get banned for it.  Fear of this causes your chest to hurt you lose 35 health")
        player_health -= 30
        time.sleep(3)



    #Question about frame rate
    print("The mysterious voice asks you another question.")
    question_two = input("Which FPS is the best FPS? 60 or 30 ")

    if question_two == "60":
        print("YES! 60fps has been known to improve player performance and make the game look better.  Anything 60fps and above is objectively better!")
        time.sleep(3)

    else: 
        print("FOOL! anything below 46fps can strain the human eye, and no it does not provide a cinematic experience.  Your eyes start hurting you and you lose 70 health")
        player_health -= 70
        time.sleep(3)



    #Final Question
    print("The mysterious voice asks you one final question")
    question_three = input(" Is PC gaming objectively better than console gaming? YES or NO")

    if question_three == "yes":
        print("Welcome to the PC Gaming Master Race!")
        time.sleep(3)


    else:
        print("There is no saving you! the mysterious voice kills you")
        player_health -= 100
        exit(0)
```

Comment: *"Can anyone help?"* is not an appropriate question for SO. Please read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you mean _"at any time"_?  You have designed your game linearly.  One thing happens, the user responds, another thing happens, and in between the program sleeps.  Please describe your desired behaviour more specifically.

Comment: Bascially I want the player to be able to check their inventory at any given point in the game.  It is a linear game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method you could use is that everytime that player writes an input he may choose to write "inventory" instead of answering. When he writes "inventory" the inventory is printed and then he has to write a new input to answer the question.

Here is a suggestion on how to do it by wrapping a question/answer block into a while loop. The player will keep getting the question "Do you want to attack or flee?" until he answers it, He can check the inventory how many times he like.

Note that you have to do this for every question so that he always has the option to check his inventory. It is not so elegant, but a completely linear game code is also not so elegant.

```
answer_is_given = False
while answer_is_given == False: # Answer has not yet been given.

    console = input("Do you want to attack or flee? ")

    if console == "inventory":
        print inventory

    elif console == "attack":
        print("Well done, you have taken your first steps to becoming a PC gamer. You also find a GTX Titan GPU")
        inventory.append('titan')
        print(inventory)
        print("")
        time.sleep(3)
        answer_is_given = True

    elif console !="attack" or console !="flee":
        print("You sat on the fence, and you fell off it.  You died")
        exit(0)

    elif console == "flee":
        print("While you fled you tripped over on cables and hurt yourself worry not you can still prove your self")
        answer_is_given = True
        time.sleep(3)
```

PS: I don't think `console !="attack" or console !="flee"` does what you intend. The answer is ALWAYS not equal to "attack" and "flee", so it will ALWAYS become True. It is impossible for something to be equal to two different things, right? I think you mean to write `console !="attack" and console !="flee"`.